# On the Realm Object Server, deleting temp files

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I would like to know more about how the temp folder on the Realm Object Server works so that I can delete files that aren't needed.

On my server, in var/lib/realm/object-server/tmp I have:

- 38 items (core.something) that are all 0 bytes from Monday August 21st.
- 272 items (core.something) that are 700mb - 3.5gb from Wednesday August 23rd.
- 1 file (core.something) that is 2.5gb from Sunday August 27th.
- 8 files (core.something) that are 1-3.5gb from Wednesday August 30th.
- 6 files (core.something) that are 1-3.4gb from Thursday August 31st.
- 9 files (core.something) that are 1-2.1gb from Friday September 1st.
- 2 files (core.something) that are 1-2.7gb from Monday September 4th.
- realm-object-server folder with folders from Aug 11th through September 4th.

My question is if I can delete anything off out of this folder.  There are giant gaps in the days that these files dates say, and especially the ones from August 23rd are taking up 342gb of space on the server. If these are outdated, is there something that will automatically remove these files, or will it hurt anything if I remove them?

It is very confusing how there is so much data being stored on the server and so little data (comparatively) being transferred in/out from the server.

(side note: we were mistakenly storing images in the realms and have since switched to storing them on devices and storing the urls, but we haven't migrated the realms that were storing photos, so they still are, but all new realms will only store references. that's why there is so much bloat. but I don't see any documentation on manually clearing out the temp files or if that is something that is done automatically, when that should be done to make sure that it is working properly.)

Comment: Well, my server filled up, so I deleted some files in order to restart the server.  Would really appreciate some insight on what I may have just broken and how to handle this going forward.

Comment: Realm uses `var/lib/realm/object-server/tmp` at runtime to store various temporary items (such as metadata for objects, permissions realm information, etc.).  If space on disk is an issue (i.e. this directory becomes too large), you can safely delete everything under this directory (after stopping ROS) and ROS will recreate as necessary on start up.  

This is larger than we typically expect this directory to get, but as you have pointed out, is likely caused by storing large binary images in this case.

Comment: Thanks @EricMaxwell.  So, I didn't stop the server before deleting those files.  It has been restarted since then. Did I potentially do any lasting damage by deleting those with the server running?  ALSO > Just to clarify, in the future, as long as I stop the server, I can clear those out, and start the server back up again and it will only create the temp files it needs?

Comment: Hi @Kurt.  Nope, no lasting damage and yes you can clear those out after stopping the server and ROS will create only the temp files it needs after starting up (and potentially others while running over time as you interact with ROS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in the var/lib/realm/object-server/tmp directory can be deleted
while ROS is stopped. There is no lasting damage from deleting those files.
The tmp files will be created by ROS when needed again.

Realm's backup service does not backup the tmp directory either.